# How do I group these objects into a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an event modal, which has a `datetime` field titled `scheduled_time`. I need to create a hash that has a day name in a certain format ('mon', 'tue' etc) as the key, and the count of events that take place on that day as the value. How can I do this?

```
{
    'mon' => 2,
    'tue' => 4,
    'wed' => 3,
    'thu' => 5,
    'fri' => 12,
    'sat' => 11,
    'sun' => 7,
}
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use `count` with a `:group` option:

```
h = Model.count(:group => %q{to_char(scheduled_time, 'dy')})
```

The specific function that you'd GROUP BY would, as usual, depend on the database; the [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) approach above would work with PostgreSQL, with MySQL you could use [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [`lower`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lower):

```
h = Model.count(:group => %q{lower(date_format(scheduled_time, '%a'))})
```

For SQLite you'd probably use [`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with a `%w` format and then convert the numbers to strings by hand.

Note that using `Model.count(:group => ...)` will give you a Hash with holes in it: if there aren't any entries in the table for that day then the Hash won't have a key for it. If you really want seven keys all the time then create a Hash with zeros:

```
h = { 'mon' => 0, 'tue' => 0, ... }
```

and then merge the `count` results into it:

```
h.merge!(Model.count(:group => ...))
```